# Error "cannot increment value-initialized list iterator" while backtracking

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a list of chars ranging from ['0', '9']. I have to permute over all possible values(10!) for which I have tried to implement backtracking. My logic is to set a char at the current place, remove this char from the list, recurse on the next place and then add this char back again to the same position in the list. The code compiles but gives me a runtime error "Debug assertion failed! Expression: cannot increment value-initialized list iterator".

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isValid(string& s)
{
    vector<int> V{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i)
        if (stoi(s.substr(i + 1, 3)) % V[i] != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

long permuteAndFind(list<char> L, string s)
{
    if (s.size() == 10)
        if (isValid(s))
            return stol(s);
        else
            return 0;

    long sum = 0;
    for (list<char>::iterator itr = L.begin(); itr != L.end(); ++itr)
    {
        char c = *itr;
        list<char>::iterator pos = L.erase(itr);
        sum += permuteAndFind(L, s + c);
        L.insert(pos, c);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    list<char> L{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7', '8', '9' };
    cout << permuteAndFind(L, "") << endl;
}
```

Edit: correct code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isValid(string& s)
{
    vector<int> V{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i)
        if (stoi(s.substr(i + 1, 3)) % V[i] != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

long permuteAndFind(list<char> L, string s)
{
    if (s.size() == 10)
        if (isValid(s))
            return stol(s);
        else
            return 0;

    long sum = 0;
    for (list<char>::iterator itr = L.begin(); itr != L.end();)
    {
        char c = *itr;
        list<char>::iterator pos = L.erase(itr);
        itr = pos;
        sum += permuteAndFind(L, s + c);
        L.insert(pos, c);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    list<char> L{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7', '8', '9' };
    cout << permuteAndFind(L, "") << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is root cause of error, but after you do `L.erase(itr)` `itr` is invalidated and you can't use it afterward. Also, `pos` can (and probably will) be invalidated by internal call to `permuteAndFind()`.

Comment: I tried adding `itr = pos;` after `L.erase(itr);` line but it's still giving the same error. I'll add the whole code. Edit: how will pos get invalidated? I am passing L by value.

Comment: Sorry, missed this. In this case `pos` not invalidated and `itr = pos;` should at least work without UB.

Comment: Tried your code with `itr = pos;` and it doesn't crash, just stuck in endless loop.

Comment: Probably because when only 1 element remains, `pos` will be `L.end()`. So I added a check before `L.insert(pos, c);` which is `if(pos != L.end())` also added the line `itr = pos` after `L.erase(itr);` but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It works (not sure if correctly) if I remove `++itr` at all. And it actually not needed, since `pos` already points to next element.

Comment: The error's gone thank you! But did you arrive at an answer? My program is still running.

Comment: I got 16695334890. Not sure if this correct or not. To speed up program try turn on optimizations, or compile in release mode.

Comment: it's right. Thanks a lot.